# Unexpected behavior while in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

Rails 3.2

I am in a Rails console session, and I am trying to find a company by id. I have a companies tables, with an id column.

I did

```
company = Company.find_by_id("1403045688")
```

Here's what I got in the console:

```
  Company Load (161.2ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`slug` = '1403045688' LIMIT 1
  EXPLAIN (162.2ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`slug` = '1403045688' LIMIT 1
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies`  WHERE `companies`.`slug` = '1403045688' LIMIT 1
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                               |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Impossible WHERE noticed after reading const tables |
+----+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-----------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.20 sec)

  Company Load (1.6ms)  SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = '1403045688' LIMIT 1
  EXPLAIN (80.7ms)  EXPLAIN SELECT `companies`.* FROM `companies` WHERE `companies`.`id` = '1403045688' LIMIT 1
EXPLAIN for: SELECT  `companies`.* FROM `companies`  WHERE `companies`.`id` = '1403045688' LIMIT 1
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
| id | select_type | table     | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | companies | const | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 182     | const |    1 |       |
+----+-------------+-----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+------+-------+
1 row in set (0.08 sec)

=> #<Company id: "1403045688", name: "AAA Electric", slug: "aaa-electric-inc", created_at: "2014-06-17 22:54:48", updated_at: "2016-03-12 05:13:26">
```

Shouldn't it go straight to search by id, instead of trying first to look using the slug? and why does it seem to be confused, and wants to have the query explained?

Comment: You seem to use `friendly_id` gem, is it? If yes, you need to update the gem as finder overriding is disabled since v5

Comment: When I grep for friendly_id in Gemfile.lock, I get:       friendly_id (~> 4.0, >= 4.0.9)
    friendly_id (4.0.10.1)
  friendly_id
Are you suggesting that I use version 5.0 of the gem?

Comment: Yes, if you don't want the default behaviour where primary_key is overridden by slug..else you always need to specify which column you are querying to. You might need to change code at other places too since the call to slug has changed e.g. `User.friendly.find(params[:id])` see https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/blob/master/README.md

Comment: friendly_id 5 has an ActiveRecord 4 dependency. I am using Rails 3.2.

Comment: Ohh yes...then you might have to bear with this..

Comment: This only happens on the test environment, not the production environment

Comment: Then probably the producrion code has taken care of this scenario but not the test cases...you need to query accordingly..

Comment: @EastsideDeveloper In general, once a software release has reached EOL by the vendor, you can expect that third-party libraries will cease updates and the voluntary help provided by Stack Overflow users and the like will cease to be useful as well. If you need to remain on software that has exceeded the vendored support period you really ought to look at paid long term support and security options, like [Rails LTS](https://railslts.com/) (starts at $169/mo).

Comment: (It's worth noting that Rails 3.2 is over 5 years old. When it was released, Siri was brand new, Kim Jong Il was still the head of North Korea, and Lyft hadn't launched yet.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Prior to version 5.0, FriendlyId overrode the default finder methods to perform friendly finds all the time](http://norman.github.io/friendly_id/file.Guide.html)

It will use both columns `slug` and `id` to find record when you use `find` method, if you want it is searched only by id, you need to change code to something like:

`company = Company.where(id: "1403045688").take`

Comment: Why would Company.where(id: "1403045688") be used instead of Company.find_by_id( "1403045688")?

Comment: Because **Prior to version 5.0, FriendlyId overrode the default finder methods to perform friendly finds all the time**, `find_by_id` is overridden to search by slug columns first, then if record is not found then id will be used to search.